# Error: Unable to resolve module ./navRoutes

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

**App .js file**

```
import React from 'react';
import Providers from './navRoutes';

const App = () => {
  return <Providers />;
};

export default App;
```

**Auth Stack file**

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen';
import SignUpScreen from './screens/SignUpScreen';
import SplashScreen from './screens/SplashScreen';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AuthStack = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none">
        <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={SignUpScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default AuthStack;
```

**Routes file**

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import AuthStack from './AuthStack';

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AuthStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

**Index file**

```
import React from 'react';
import Routes from './Routes';

const Providers = () => {
  return (
    // <AuthProvider>
    <Routes />
    // {/* </AuthProvider> */}
  );
};

export default Providers;
```

**All the files are .js file and they are in the navRoutes folder except app.js file . app.jsand navRoutes are in same directory**

**Error**

> error: Error: Unable to resolve module ./navRoutes from
> D:\Programs\React Native\Sucessfully Project\Image Art
> Gallery\ImageGallery\App.js:
>
> None of these files exist:   *
> navRoutes(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
>
> - navRoutes\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
>   1 | import React from 'react';
>
> > 2 | import Providers from './navRoutes';
> > |                        ^   3 |   4 | const App = () => {   5 |   return ;
> > at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\Programs\React Native\Sucessfully Project\Image Art
> > Gallery\ImageGallery\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:211:15)
> > at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\Programs\React Native\Sucessfully Project\Image Art
> > Gallery\ImageGallery\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:413:43)
> > at Object.resolve (D:\Programs\React Native\Sucessfully Project\Image Art
> > Gallery\ImageGallery\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:317:42)
> > at resolve (D:\Programs\React Native\Sucessfully Project\Image Art Gallery\ImageGallery\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:629:33)
> > at D:\Programs\React Native\Sucessfully Project\Image Art Gallery\ImageGallery\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:645:26
> > at Array.reduce ()
> > at resolveDependencies (D:\Programs\React Native\Sucessfully Project\Image Art
> > Gallery\ImageGallery\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:644:33)
> > at D:\Programs\React Native\Sucessfully Project\Image Art Gallery\ImageGallery\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:329:33
> > at Generator.next ()
> > at asyncGeneratorStep (D:\Programs\React Native\Sucessfully Project\Image Art
> > Gallery\ImageGallery\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:137:24)

Comment: have you restarted metro and rebuild your project?

Comment: ya 2 times i restart and rebuild my project